# Скрытие контента в таблице

Tags: css

Всем привет есть таблица. Каждому блоку таблицы задан определенный процентный width который в сумме дает 100% для корректного отображения всего содержимого на разных экранах. Есть длинный заголовок часть которого я хочу скрыть следующим:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Это нужно для того что бы длинный заголовок оставался на 1 строке — но проблема в том что это правило не работает в таблице. Применив его содержимое растягивается на всю ширину и скрытия с многоточием не происходит. Подскажите где копать кто знает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте ячейку блочным элементом `display: inline-block;`

```css
td {
  border: solid;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</td>
<td>
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо друг большое

Comment: @Hronoboy рад помочь, обращайтесь

Comment: Маленькое примечание с display: inline-block;проблема не решилась с -     display: grid; все работает нормально. Еще раз спасибо.